# Flutter response non-json structure form server getting html code

Tags: dart, flutter

when i connect to server for checking username and password like with this structure

```
{
"Username":"1",
"Password":"1"
}
```

i get `0` or `1`, without any json format, first letters of username and password are Capital letters, **U**sername,**P**assword,

now i want to get this response with flutter and `post` http verb

`UserInformation` class

```
class UserInformation {
  String Username;
  String Password;

  UserInformation(this.Username, this.Password);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> json = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    json['Username'] = this.Username;
    json['Password'] = this.Password;

    return json;
  }
}
```

`LoginRepository` class:

```
class LoginRepository {

  Future<int> authenticate(
      {@required String username, @required String password}) async {
    UserInformation userInformation = UserInformation(username, password);
    /*this line print {Username: 1, Password: 1}*/
    print(userInformation.toJson().toString());

    final response = await http.post(
        Constants.loginApi, body: userInformation.toJson());
    final responseString = jsonDecode(response.body);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return responseString;
    } else {
      throw Exception('fail to get response');
    }
  }
}
```

and then this output is response from server:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
ï»¿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First: Check for statusCode before accessing response.body. If the call fails, response.body will be an empty String and jsonDecode will fail.

Second: Since you don't get a json formated answer, there is no need to call jsonDecode with the response. `final int responseInt = response.body` should be enough (maybe you will need `int.parse(response.body);` needs to be tested.